# How to Record a call in AsteriskNOW?

Tags: sip, asterisk

How to enable Call Recording on AsteriskNOW ?
I am a student doing my final year project in this domain.I have installed asterisk server and able to make the connections.
But unable to record the calls.

I have googled a lot and found something about monitor command.But I am still struggling where to place the monitor command in extensions.confPlease do help me.
Thanks in advance

Regards,
Rashmi.R

Comment: Can you show us part of your `extensions.conf` file with `Monitor` command or where you `Answer` incoming call?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use [`Monitor` cmd](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Monitor) ? If not: add it to your dialplan (there is also `StopMonitor` cmd). If you already use it then you will have to show us more details: dialplan, maybe some fragment of asterisk log with error.

There is example of my dialplan with `Monitor` cmd:

```
[afterwork_service]
exten => s,1,NoOp
exten => s,n,Answer
exten => s,n,PlayBack(recording_starting_info)
exten => s,n,Wait(2)
exten => s,n,Monitor(wav,${CALLFILENAME})
```

It plays info about recording starting and then customer can record praises to our service, software and developers :)

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your response.I know about the monitor command.But I just don't know where to place the monitor command in extensions.conf kindly help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Michal,Sorry for disturbing you.Ijust want to know what does [afterwork_service] mean.Kindly help.thanks in advance

Comment: I think it is just a context, which plays some audio while there is no people in office

Comment: Yuriy is right. It plays message and then record compl^H^H^h^H praises for our great service :)